# HashMap Difficulties

Tags: java, maps, hashtable

This is a school assignment. Overall this should read a text file, add words from it to a hash table. I've coded it out, but I'm testing it and it's giving me some problems. When I try to find the index of the object, it always returns -1, meaning it's saying the words aren't in the array even if they are. There are a few other problems as well. It's giving me a headache.

```
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.LinkedList;


public class MyMap<K,V> implements Iterable<MyMap.MyEntry<K,V>> {
        int collision; // maintain the current count of collisions here.
        int slots = 0;
        int key = 0;
        MyEntry<K,V> tempPair;
        LinkedList<MyEntry<K,V>> [] bucketArray;
        int keyMod;

    /**
     * Create a MyMap instance with the specified number of 
     * buckets.
     * 
     * @param buckets the number of buckets to make in this map
     */
    public MyMap(int buckets) {
        slots = buckets;
        bucketArray = (LinkedList<MyEntry<K,V>> [])new LinkedList[buckets];

    }

    /**
     * Puts an entry into the map.  If the key already exists, 
     *  it's value is updated with the new value and the previous
     *  value is returned.
     *
     * @param key the object used as a key to retrieve the value
     * @param value the object stored in association with the key
     * 
     * @return the previously stored value or null if the key is new
     */
    public V put(K key, V value) {
            // don't forget hashcodes can be any integer value.  You'll
            // need to compress them to ensure they give you a valid bucket.

        MyEntry<K,V> tempPair = new MyEntry<K,V>(key, value);
        Word newWord = new Word((String)key);
        keyMod = newWord.hashCode((String)key) % slots;


        if ((bucketArray[keyMod]) == null){
            LinkedList<MyEntry<K,V>> firstList = new LinkedList<MyEntry<K,V>>();
            firstList.add(tempPair);
            bucketArray[keyMod] = firstList;
            return null;
            }

        else {

            int indexNode = bucketArray[keyMod].indexOf(tempPair);

            if (indexNode == -1) {
                bucketArray[keyMod].add(tempPair);
                collision += 1;
                //System.out.println(indexNode );
                return null;
                }
            else {
                MyEntry<K,V> oldNode = bucketArray[keyMod].get(indexNode);
                V oldValue = oldNode.value;
                oldNode.value = tempPair.value;
                //System.out.println(indexNode );
                return oldValue;
            }
        }

    }

    /**
     * Retrieves the value associated with the specified key.  If 
     * it exists, the value stored with the key is returned, if no 
     * value has been associated with the key, null is returned.
     * 
     * @param key the key object whose value we wish to retrieve
     * @return the associated value, or null
     */
    public V get(K key) {
        //MyEntry<K,V> tempPair = new MyEntry<K,V>(key,value);


        Word newWord = new Word((String)key);
        int keyMod = newWord.hashCode((String)key) % slots;

        if (bucketArray[keyMod] == null) {
            return null;
        }

        else { 

            int temp = bucketArray[keyMod].indexOf(key);
            if (temp == -1) {
                return null;
                }

            else {
                MyEntry<K,V> tempNode = bucketArray[keyMod].get(temp);
                return tempNode.value;
                }
        }

    }

    /**
     *
     * I've implemented this method, however, you must correctly 
     * maintain the collisions member variable.
     *
     * @return the current count of collisions thus far.
     */
    public int currentCollisions(K key) {
        return collision;
    }
    /**
     * Looks through the entire bucket where the specified key
     * would be found and counts the number of keys in this bucket
     * that are not equal to the current key, yet still have the
     * same hash code.
     * 
     * @param key
     * @return a count of collisions
     */
    public int countCollisions(K key) {
        Word newKey = new Word((String) key);
        int keyMod = newKey.hashCode((String) key) % slots;
        if (bucketArray[keyMod].indexOf(key) == -1){
            return bucketArray[keyMod].size();
            }
        return (bucketArray[keyMod].size()-1);
    }
    /**
     * Removes the value associated with the specifed key, if it exists.
     * @param key the key used to find the value to remove.
     * @return the value if the key was found, or null otherwise.
     */
    public V remove(K key) {
        Word newWord = new Word((String)key);
        //int keyMod = newWord.hashCode((String)key) % slots;
        int tempNodeIndex = bucketArray[newWord.hashCode((String)key)].indexOf(key);
        if (tempNodeIndex == -1) {
            return null;
            }
        else{
        tempPair = bucketArray[key.hashCode()].get(tempNodeIndex);
        V returnValue = tempPair.value;
        tempPair.value = null;
        return returnValue;}
    }
    /**
     * Returns the number of entries in this map
     * @return the number of entries.
     */
    public int size() {
        int size = 0;
        for (int i =0; i< bucketArray.length; i++){
            size = bucketArray[i].size() + size;
        }
        return size;
    }

    /**
     * Creates and returns a new Iterator object that 
     * iterates over the keys currently in the map. The iterator 
     * should fail fast, and does not need to implement the remove
     * method.
     * 
     * @return a new Iterator object  
     */
    public Iterator<MyEntry<K,V>> iterator() {

        return null;
    }

    public static class MyEntry<K,V> {
        K key;
        V value;

        public MyEntry(K k, V v) {
            key = k;
            value = v;
        }
    }


}
```

Here is the Word Class

```
/* The reason you can't extend String Class is because String is a final class and you can not have 
 * a subclass that might alter components of a final class. Since the word class would extend the 
 * String class, it would have the capability to change variables within the String Final Class.
 */

public class Word {

    String word;

    /**
     * Creates a Word object representing the specified String
     * 
     * @param w the String version of this word.
     */
    public Word(String w) {
        word = w;

    }

    /**
     * Returns a hashcode for this Word -- an integer whose value is based on the 
     * word's instance data. Words that are .equals() *must* have the same hashcode.
     * However, the converse need not hold -- that is, it *is*  acceptable for 
     * two words that are not .equals() to have the same hashcode.
     */
    public int hashCode(String word) {
         int code = 0;
         for ( int i =0; i<word.length(); i++){
            code = word.charAt(i) + code;
         }

         return code;    //word.hashCode();

        //int hashCode = 0;
        //for ( int i = 0; i<word.length(); i++) {
            //hashCode = Math.abs(hashCode*13 + word.charAt(i));
        //}
        //System.out.println(hashCode);
        //return hashCode;
    }

    /**
     * Returns true if and only if this Word object represents the same
     * sequence of characters as the specified object. Here, you can assume
     * that the object being passed in will be a Word. 
     */
    public boolean equals(Object o) { 
        String passedIn = o.toString();
        boolean returnValue = word.equals(passedIn);

        return returnValue;
    }

    /**
     * This method returns the string representation of the object.
     * A correct implementation will return the String representation of the
     * word that is actually being stored. ie., if you had a word object representing
     * 'hi', it should return 'hi'
     */
    public String toString() {
        String thisString = word;
        return thisString;
    }
}
```

Here is the beginnings of my tester:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;


public class Tester<K,V> {

    public static void main(String [] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

        MyMap<String, Integer> pain = new MyMap<String, Integer>(3000);

        Scanner s = new Scanner (new File("pg4.txt"));

        while (s.hasNext()) {
            String word = s.next();
            Integer value = (Integer) pain.get(word);

            if (value == null) {
                pain.put(word, 1);
            }
            else {
                value +=1;
                pain.put(word, value);
                }
            }
        s.close();
        pain.put("the",1);
        pain.put("the",5);
        pain.get("the");
        System.out.println("'the' gives this many collisions: " + pain.get("the") );
        pain.remove("the");
        System.out.println("'the' gives this many collisions: " + pain.get("the") );


    }
}
```

Comment: Shoot. Sorry. Disregard the print statements in the tester.

Comment: You can shorten your `toString()` method to simply `return word;`, there's no need to store it in a local before returning it

Comment: Thanks. I'll go ahead and do that so it's a bit more "stylish."

Comment: It's not so much a matter of style as it is of efficiency - by storing it in a local variable first, your program needs to set aside an amount of memory to hold the reference, then set it, then return it. It also almost immediately becomes eligible for garbage collection, so you're creating a tiny bit more work for the GC to do when it runs. Skipping the local variable avoids all that (and you also don't have to type as much, which when you're writing code all day is a big plus).

Comment: Out of interest - have you been forbidden from using the String class' `hashCode()` implementation? If not, I'd just use that instead of rolling your own

Comment: Forbidden. We had to implement a hashmap method from his instructions where we take that sum of the char of each letter. Then we were  suppose to come up with our own.

Comment: @AdrieneNorikoShanders You are probably supposed to have a `MyMap<Word, Integer>` for the assignment then. The way you are doing it right now where you create a `Word` just to cast `K` and call `hashCode` is just nonsensical (sorry).

Answer (score 1):

1. [`indexOf`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html#indexOf-java.lang.Object-) uses `equals` for comparisons, so your calls to `indexOf` do not work. You need to implement `equals` for `MyEntry`.

   ```
   public static class MyEntry<K,V> {
       K key;
       V value;

       public MyEntry(K k, V v) {
           key = k;
           value = v;
       }

       @Override
       public int hashCode() {
           // (overriding hashCode
           // just because we are overriding equals)
           return ( key == null ? 0 : key.hashCode() );
       }

       @Override
       public boolean equals(Object o) {
           if(!(o instanceof MyEntry<?, ?>))
               return false;
           MyEntry<?, ?> that = (MyEntry<?, ?>)o;
           return( this.key == null ?
               that.key == null : this.key.equals(that.key)
           );
       }
   }
   ```

   If you don't do this, then you need to create your own `indexOf` method where you loop through the `LinkedList` yourself.
2. Your `remove` method does not actually do a removal, just set the value to null.

   ```
   tempPair = bucketArray[key.hashCode()].get(tempNodeIndex);
   V returnValue = tempPair.value;
   tempPair.value = null;
   ```

   More correctly it would be:

   ```
   tempPair = bucketArray[key.hashCode()].remove(tempNodeIndex);
   return tempPair.value;
   ```
3. As far as I can tell, you do not need the `Word` class at all. Your casting to `String` makes assumptions about what the type of `K` is, which is dubious for a generic class. (What if I have a `MyMap<Long, Double>`?)

   You are only using it to get a `hashCode` which your `K` will already have (because `hashCode` is declared on `java.lang.Object`).

   You could use `hashCode` from a temp `MyEntry` like I defined above or call it directly:

   ```
   int keyMod = ( key == null ? 0 : key.hashCode() ) % slots;
   ```
4. To get your `Word` class working, you need to override `hashCode` correctly:

   ```
   // now you can call hashCode() on a Word
   // when a Word is passed in to MyMap as a key
   @Override
   public int hashCode() {
        int code = 0;
        // 'word' now refers to the instance variable
        for ( int i =0; i<word.length(); i++){
           code = word.charAt(i) + code;
        }

        return code;
   }

   // also implementing equals correctly, but your
   // implementation in the question probably did
   // not cause an error
   @Override
   public boolean equals(Object o) {
       if(!(o instanceof Word))
           return false;
       String passedIn = ((Word)o).word;
       boolean returnValue = word.equals(passedIn);
       return returnValue;
   }
   ```

   Then you will be able to use a `MyMap<Word, Integer>`.

Comment: Part of this was practice. My teacher specified we had to write two different hash functions for this assignment and test both of them to see how collisions change. He also wanted us to implement the rest of the word class. No we don't really use it but...that was his decision.

Comment: We're only suppose to remove the value for the remove method

Comment: See my above comment then, you are probably supposed to have a `MyMap<Word, Integer>`. This wouldn't really change my answer.

Comment: *"We're only suppose to remove the value for the remove method"* Then you don't need to change your `remove` method but this definition of a removal is different from every other map in existence. The rest of my answer still applies.

Comment: I apologize for the confusion. The methods were outlined and named by the professor. It was just my job to implement them. If you read the comments above each method, you can see specifically what they are supposed to be doing.

Comment: @AdrieneNorikoShanders:  In addition to what Radiodef pointed out, `Word.hashCode(String word)` does _not_ override `Object.hashCode()`... so any _other_ class that relies on hashing will (probably) get different hash codes for "equal" `Word` objects.  Use the `@Override` annotation to have the compiler catch errors like this for you.  (`hashCode`, `equals`, and `toString` are the usual suspects.)

Also, `Word.equals` will throw a `NullPointerException` if it ever gets tested against a `null`... or if it is ever constructed with a `null`, for that matter.

Comment: @AdrieneNorikoShanders I read the comments. ; ) I just made assumptions because e.g. there is no logical difference between `put(k, null)` and `remove(k)` with this definition of `remove`. Please take the time to see if my answer has properly addressed the problems you've observed and, if so, consider accepting it. http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/244864

Comment: That's an interesting point. I'll pass it on to my professor and ask him about it.

Comment: I'm not sure if what you've pointed out is what is giving me the -1 index. I'm also not sure if I'm allowed to change MyEntry from KV to Word and Integer(mostly because this was how my professor set this Problem Set up). I'll ask my professor and get back to you. I've been told to try using a for loop. Can one of you explain further why indexOf won't work in this instance? I'm trying to grab the index of the node.

Comment: *"I'm also not sure if I'm allowed to change MyEntry from KV to Word and Integer"* I haven't suggested this. *"Can one of you explain further why indexOf won't work in this instance?"* I explained this in my answer. `indexOf` uses `equals`.

Answer (score 0):

I found a few problems in my MyMap class where I wasn't constructing correctly. I found the error and fixed it. My tests were also causing errors. I corrected them. There were no problems in my Word Class. Once I corrected these the map constructed correctly, all methods worked.